# How do I add a semi colon between text fragments but not at the end of text fragments?

Tags: xml, xslt

When my xml code has un the **Conditions node** Address and Party elements, a semi colon is added after the party name. 
I do not want the **semi colon** after the name because there is nothing else after that. 
**Here is the output:**

Respondent's access to the following party(ies) at the following place(s) of employment is limited as follows: Brown, Rayne**;**  1048 Regions RD, St Paul, MN, 55101
    08

**Here my output is displaying a semi colon at the end of the condition text element even though there is only one party name. 
How do I change my xslt so that this semi colon is not displayed when there is only one party name?**

Petitioner is awarded sole physical and legal custody of the following child(ren): Brown, Rayne;  
        09

**My xml code:**

```
        <Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="BCA PO Notification" MessageID="57832809" xmlns="">
        <ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="2563" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
            <ProtectionOrderParties>
                <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1614450754">
                    <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                        <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1615262152" FormattedName="Brown, Rayne"/>
                    </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                    <Added>12/29/2014</Added>
                    <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                        <Petitioner>true</Petitioner>
                        <FilingParty>false</FilingParty>
                        <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                        <Minor>false</Minor>
                    </ProtectionOrderConnection>
                    <MNProtectionOrderAdditional InternalID="2604" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
            <Conditions>
                <Condition>
                    <Code Word="03F1EXPC">03.F.1 Respondent must not call/enter place of employment</Code>
                    <Description>Respondent must not call or enter the place of employment of the following party(ies). This includes all land, parking lots, and buildings of the following addresses:</Description>
                    <Parties>
                        <Party InternalPartyID="1614450754"/>
                    </Parties>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address InternalAddressID="1618211350"/>
                    </Addresses>
                </Condition>
                <Condition>
                    <Code Word="03F2EXPC">03.F.2 Respondent's access at place of employment</Code>
                    <Description>Respondent's access to the following party(ies) at the following place(s) of employment is limited as follows: </Description>
                    <Parties>
                        <Party InternalPartyID="1614450754"/>
                    </Parties>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address InternalAddressID="1618211350"/>
                    </Addresses>
                </Condition>
            </Conditions>
        </MNProtectionOrderAdditional>
                </ProtectionOrderParty>
            </ProtectionOrderParties>
            <MNProtectionOrderAdditional InternalID="2559" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                </xsl:if>           
</MNProtectionOrderAdditional>
        </ProtectionOrder>
</Integration>
```

**My xslt code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="MNProtectionOrderAdditional/Conditions/Condition">
            <ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
                <ext:ConditionText>
                    <xsl:variable name="vCondition">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description)"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
                            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
                                <!--<xsl:text>; </xsl:text>-->
                                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                                <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Addresses/Address">
                            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine2">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine3">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine4">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine4"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($vCondition,string-length($vCondition)-1,2)='; '">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($vCondition,1,string-length($vCondition)-2)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$vCondition"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </ext:ConditionText>
                <ext:ConditionCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\MNCISCodes\ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping.xml'))
/ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping/Mapping[MNCISCode=current()/Code/@Word]/BCACode"/>
                </ext:ConditionCode>
            </ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**Updated xslt**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.mn.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="ProtectionOrder">
        <ext:ProtectionOrder>
<!--ext:ProtectionOrderCondition-->
            <xsl:for-each select="MNProtectionOrderAdditional/Conditions/Condition">
                <ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
                    <ext:ConditionText>
                        <xsl:variable name="vCondition">
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description)"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
                                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                                    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Addresses/Address">
                                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
                                    <xsl:if test="AddressLine1">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
                                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="AddressLine2">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
                                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="AddressLine3">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
                                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="AddressLine4">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine4"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="substring($vCondition,string-length($vCondition)-1,2)='; '">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($vCondition,1,string-length($vCondition)-2)"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vCondition"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </ext:ConditionText>
                    <ext:ConditionCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\MNCISCodes\ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping.xml'))
    /ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping/Mapping[MNCISCode=current()/Code/@Word]/BCACode"/>
                    </ext:ConditionCode>
                </ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ext:ProtectionOrder>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*I decided to post a new post because it seems like people think the previous one was resolved.*"  Please don't do that.

Comment: What's your advice?  Should I delete one of them?

Comment: Did you notice many of your recent questions received downvotes only and caused a lot of confusion? Time to step back and look at the basics of XSLT _and_ the [basics of asking questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) _and_ at [how to create a good code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay good advice.  Should I delete this post?

Comment: In my opinion, no. I don't see how this relates to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610450/how-do-i-only-display-one-element-and-not-two-based-on-lowest-internalpartyid) - even if you suggest it describes the same problem. So, I would not close it as a duplicate. But this new post has the same problems again: you need to provide _all_ information that is necessary to diagnose the problem, i.e. a full stylesheet - and as **short** as possible, try to isolate the problem you are facing.

Comment: Just updated my answer for the updated question. Hope this solves the issue, as extended comments should be avoided on Stackoverflow and you would need more than 20 rep to use the chat feature where it would be easier to clarify possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a misunderstanding, but wouldn't it work like requested if this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties
         /ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/
         ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

would just be changed into that:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties
         /ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/
         ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Currently the `;` is added for the last element (when `position() = last()`), but I guess you only want to have it between multiple parties (if there are any), so it should work if you change this to `position() != last()`.

**Update:** As mentioned in comment, suggested approach doesn't work like intended. Not knowing the input XML but assuming this could work because, like mentioned, it should be  based on the amount of Party elements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties
         /ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/
         ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Moving the `<xsl:if test="position() != last()">` statement to the `<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">` instead of the inner loop should write `;` after each `Party` if it's not the last `Party`.

**Update:** For the updated question regarding the issue mentioned in the comments - I don't know if I fully understand the problem. Regarding the updated XSLT, it should be as follows: in case there is more than one `Party`, a `;` will be added between each `Party` using `position() != last()`. As I understand, there should also be a `;` after the `Party` name in case it will be followed by an `Address`. Currenty, there won't be any `;` after the last `Party` name regardless if there's only one or more `party` elements. I suggest following approach: count the `Address` nodes and check if the position of the `Party` element is `last()` and if there's an `Address`. In this case, the variable `addressCount` is `> 0`, which is written as `&gt; 0` (escaped):

```
<xsl:variable name="addressCount" select="count(Addresses/Address)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties
         /ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/
         ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last() or (position() = last()
                and $addressCount &gt; 0)">
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Using

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last() or (position() = last() 
  and $addressCount &gt; 0)">
  <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

means: write `;` if it's not the last `Party` (adding `;` between `Party` names in case there's more than one `Party`) *or*, in the case it's the last `Party` and the count of `Address` elements is `> 0`.

Comment: The problem I am running into is that when I use `<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>; </xsl:text></xsl:if>` and test it with 2 parties in my xml in the conditiontext, I am not getting a semi colon between the names. However, when I only have one party in my xml conditiontext, a semi colon is added at the end of the name which is not what I want. When I remove the ! and leave the code like this `<xsl:if test="position() = last()"><xsl:text>; </xsl:text></xsl:if>` a semi colon is added when xml has 2 parties but then it is also adding a semi colon when xml has only one party.

Comment: @user3781064 Just updated my answer, if this still won't work it would be better to have more of the input xml in the question as it's kind of a guess.

Comment: Thank you so much mathias_h. Moving the test position statement outside the party loop worked! Again I want to thank you. I will now mark this as solved and your answer as the correct way that solved my problem.

Comment: The problem I have is that when the node **Conditions** has two elements under **Condition** the **Party** and **Address**, the semi colon is added even though there is only one name. How can I remove the semi colon?

Comment: @user3781064 I thought the issue would be solved - from what I can see this shouldn't happen if the xslt is adjusted like mentioned (the position test inside the party loop, but outside of the inner loop). Maybe a misunderstanding. Is the semi c after the party name or after the address?

Comment: The semi colon is added after the name when there is nothing else after the name. If there is address after the name the semi colon is added which is fine.

Comment: This is working when there is only a name not followed by address. However, when a name is followed by an address, the semi colon is not added after the name but it should be.

Comment: @user3781064 Not easy to guess without knowing the current xslt. Could you add the updated xslt in your question? And pls don't change the question, just add it at the end in edit mode and write something like "Update" above it.

Comment: I have updated my xslt as you suggested. Please let me know what else I should do to get the help I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did as suggested, I move the code inside the for each statement.

**xslt Code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
   <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
   <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```